# git removing a development branch from remote git server

Tags: git

I created a branch, worked on it, merged it with the base branch and now want to delete it. The branch was created on the git remote server as well.

Now when I ran git branch -d branch, it removed it and I pushed it. But i still see the branch on the git remote server.

I saw a similar issue earlier when I created this branch and I was not able to see it on the remote git server.

I am even able to checkout from this branch.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove branch on the remote

```
git push remote :refs/heads/development
```

Comment: Or equivalent: `git push remote :development`

Comment: @Koraktor, yes, that would do, unless the ref is elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on these answers, each branch basically exists in three places:

- On the remote server, e.g. `origin/foo`
- Your local copy of `origin/foo` (which is updated via `git fetch`)
- The local branch `foo` (which is updated via `git merge origin/foo` following `git fetch` - or more commonly, both are done together via `git pull`).

`git branch -d` deletes the last of these three, namely the local branch. `git branch -d -r` will remove *your copy* of the remote branch (or you can run `git remote prune origin` after deleting local branches).

To delete the branch on the remote server though, you must use `git push`. The old syntax for this is `git push origin :branchname`. This is because the syntax is `localref:remoteref`, for example it is possible to push a local branch on your machine to a remote branch with a different name, e.g. `git push origin localbranch:remotebranch`. If you leave the `localbranch` part empty, you're telling git to push *nothing* to the remote branch, deleting it.

If that's confusing, don't worry, the git developers agree with you. Newer versions have a `--delete` option so `git push origin --delete branchname` does the same thing as `git push origin :branchname`, but its intent is much more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You delete the remote branch with the following arcane command:

```
git push origin :newfeature
```

You may want to update your index, so the tracking branch gets removed as well:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```